# What exactly do HTML templates do?

Tags: html

Libraries like handlebars and underscorejs allow you to template you html but what exactly does this mean? What functionality do templates provide that a library like jquery cannot

Comment: you should try a tutorial. it is the best way to see their advantages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery` manipulates the DOM with javascript by adding, for example, toggling. So it's an addition to a HTML template that already exists.

Taken from the Underscore site:

```
It's the tie to go along with jQuery's tux, and Backbone.js's suspenders.
```

Underscore is more suited to data manipulation and brings many Ruby methods to JavaScript. There is some crossover, but not enough to make them mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

html templates allow a programmer to use built in python libraries to connect html to a programming languague like python.